# How to avoid starting and ending double quotes in rails string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

My string is like this `"SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1"` but when store this in variable

```
new_string="SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"
```

and i interpolate like this "#{new_string}". The value is like

```
""SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1""
```

Update 1:
This is my scenario where i need to use that one

```
$redis.subscribe("RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","SHN::test::cg1") do |on|
 #hardcoded values inside braces
end
```

but i need to pass a variable to form string like above(inside braces) whT I tried

```
$redis.subscribe("#{new_string}") do |on|
 #interpolated value inside braces
end
```

update 2: Answer
 I just need to pass the new_string as a array itself no need to convert to string this is the answer for **MY scenario**

```
$redis.subscribe(new_string) do |on|
     #interpolated value inside braces
 end
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new_string` is actually an Array, not a String! The reason why is because you actually have three strings separated by commas, so Ruby parses it as an array of strings:

```
irb> new_string="SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"
=> ["SHN::test::cg1", "RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1", "MDC::test::cg1"]
```

When you then interpolate it into a new string, Ruby calls `.to_s` on the Array, which (depending on your version of Ruby) produces what you're seeing:

```
irb> ["SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"].to_s
=> "[\"SHN::test::cg1\", \"RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1\", \"MDC::test::cg1\"]"

irb> puts ["SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"].to_s
["SHN::test::cg1", "RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1", "MDC::test::cg1"]
```

To fix this, simply make `new_string` an actual string (by fixing the syntax in your definition). Or, convert the array to a string yourself, e.g.:

```
irb> "#{new_string.join('')}"
=> "SHN::test::cg1RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1MDC::test::cg1"
```

Comment: but i need a string like this["SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"] for specific purpose.

Comment: You'll need to encode that string in a way that lets the Ruby parser know you want it all to be in a string exactly like that, then. The simplest way to do so is to use single quotes (since the string itself already uses double-quotes), like so: `new_string = '["SHN::test::cg1","RDC::TEST::CONFIG 1","MDC::test::cg1"]'`

Comment: Thanks for sharing of your knowledge and time .i got the answer from other thread .We can just pass that array framed is enough.